# How can I pass a variable to a callback function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

See the code please:

```
$('.delete_group').click(function(e) {
   var group_id = $(this).attr('placeholder');
   e.preventDefault();
   confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Group?", 
      function deleteGroup(XXX) {
         window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/deleteGroupById/' + group_id;
      }
   );
});
```

I need to pass the group_id to location XXX.

thanks everyone.

Comment: `confirm()` doesn't take a callback argument.

Comment: `->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm `<-`

Comment: here confirm is just a function name, that is called here....

Comment: can you post your confirm function code please

Comment: Well, if `confirm` is not the same as `window.confirm` and it takes a callback function, and you want to call that function with a particular argument, you might want to look into [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

[`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) will return a boolean value. `True` if user selects "OK", else `False`.

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Group?"))
{
  //User clicked "OK". Do the deletion code
}
else
{
  //User clicked cancel.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteGroup(group_id) {
    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/deleteGroupById/' + group_id;
}

$('.delete_group').click(function(e) {
   var group_id = $(this).attr('placeholder');
   e.preventDefault();
   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Group?")) {
      deleteGroup(group_id);
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out a parenthesis, I fixed it. I wonder why you couldn't figure that out yourself from the error message, though.

Comment: i just trying fastly all of your code, so spent no time to figure out why is the error
thanks Barmar

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
$('.delete_group').click(function (e) {
    var group_id = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Group?");
    if (answer) {
        deleteGroup(group_id);
    }
});

function deleteGroup(XXX) {
    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/deleteGroupById/' + XXX;
}
```

Comment: sorry... i must use call back function there

Comment: @NazmulHasanNero Where must you use a call back function? `window.confirm` doesn't take any.

Comment: please look at this:
confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Group?", 
      function deleteGroup(XXX) {
         window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/deleteGroupById/' + group_id;
      }
   );
I must use this function, it is another function that is called here

Comment: @NazmulHasanNero That is not the right syntax. `confirm` doesn't take a second argument. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: thnx tewathia I realized it now